# C# UDP Socket.ReceiveFrom timeout without using BeginReceiveFrom or Exceptions

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, udp

I'm trying to implement a basic UDP client. One of its functions is the ability to probe computers to see if a UDP server is listening. I need to scan lots of these computers quickly.

I can't use the `Socket.BeginReceiveFrom` method and run a timeout waiting for it to complete, because callbacks may occur after the timeout is over, and seeing as many computers are being probed quickly, I found that later callbacks ended up using modified data as a new probe was already underway when the callback was finally invoked.

I can't use the `Socket.ReceiveFrom` method and set a `Socket.ReceiveTimeout` because the `SocketException` being thrown+handled takes a long time (not sure why, I'm not running much code to handle it), meaning it takes about 2 seconds per computer rather than 100ms like hoped.

Is there any way of running a timeout on a synchronous call to `ReceiveFrom` without using exceptions to determine when the call has failed/succeeded? Or is there a tactic I've not yet taken that you think could work?

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: You can pass a cookie of some sort to `BeginReceiveFrom` that you get back in the callback, which you can then use to determine whether the callback was from the server that you expected.

Comment: I tried that, but found that if a callback was late, another probe would have already started and changed the address that the cookie would be checked against :/

Comment: Use a separately new'ed cookie for each `BeginReceiveFrom` call.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to rewrite the probe code using TCP.

However, I later discovered the `Socket.ReceiveFromAsync` method which, seeing as it only receives a single datagram per call, would have made life easier.